# Linux: getting detailed stats for a single HTTP request?

Tags: linux, dns, performance, http, command-line

I'm writing a script to determine the performance of a service from a client's point of view.

To that effect, I need to be able to determine a few stats for each HTTP request like:

- DNS lookup time
- TCP connect time
- TCP transmission time

I'd need millisecond resolution for the values.

What would be the command(s) or perl/python/php libraries that could give me such information?

Comment: Please take a look at the [help center](http://serverfault.com/help) to see why your question if off-topic here.

Comment: Would you kindly ellaborate on that? What is specifically off-topic in this question? From the help page I can see 2 items which cover this question as on-topic: Server and Workstation operating systems, hardware, and software; Operations, maintenance, and monitoring

Comment: It's a programming question, essentially. Arent' the various web developer tools on Firefox and Chrome already doing what you want anyway?

Comment: @SvW They don't (can't) get the DNS lookup time. It is essentially a network benchmarking question, which belongs to the field of the system administrators. To the professionals. Of course he could ask this from the viewpoint of a programmer as well, which resulted a little bit differing answers.

Comment: Use Firebug extension on Firefox. The _Network_ tab on it will show you DNS time, connect time, download time...

Comment: @SvW: While the developer tools in current browsers could get me the information I want, they cannot be automated and are not fit for unattended data collection. My purpose is to set up monitoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `-w` option of `curl(1)`. It allows you to do things like the following:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -w "DNS Lookup: %{time_namelookup}\nTCP Connect: %{time_connect}\nTotal: %{time_total}\n" http://www.serverfault.com

DNS Lookup: 0.004
TCP Connect: 0.104
Total: 0.206
```

This means roughly that DNS was looked up in 4 ms, before 100 ms later the TCP connection was ready and 102 ms later all data was transmitted.